# admin-on-rest in create form - How to populate the list in dropdown based on another input value

Tags: admin-on-rest

I am using admin-on-rest in my project. I am facing one scenario where I could not find solution. Could someone please help me in how to populate the list in dropdown based on another input value in create form. (Example: populate 'State' list based on 'Country' change like this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using [aor-dependent-input](https://github.com/marmelab/aor-dependent-input).

You can find an example in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5xwv91v4n4

Look for the `PostCreate` component which has `category` and `subcategory` inputs.

Comment: thnks for your reply gildas. If you post any example code, it will be more helpful. Can you?

Comment: Mark it as answered ?